# Arterial line location and PPG sensor location

Tags: mimic-iii

1) From which artery the ABP signal was collected?
2) Where was the PPG device located? Fingertip? What wavelength was used?

Answer (score 2):

https://physionet.org/mimic2/mimic2_waveform_overview.shtml:

> - ABP: arterial blood pressure (invasive, from one of the radial arteries)
> - ART: arterial blood pressure (invasive, from the other radial artery)

FYI:

- [How much more accurate are indwelling arterial catheters compared to standard, non-invasive blood pressure monitoring?](https://health.stackexchange.com/q/1602/43)
- [How much impact does the location of measurement of blood pressure have on the quality of the obtained blood pressure signal?](https://health.stackexchange.com/q/4646/43)